# Checking payer balance in PayPal NVP API?

Tags: paypal

I integrate PayPal Express Checkout in a Java web project and I want to know if before a transaction processing it need to be checked if the buyer has sufficient means (funds) in the account or PayPal does this automatically? If so, where can I set the redirect link in case the account balance is less than the amount to be paid?

Cause for example I have 2 sandbox accounts, one Personal (where I have 100$) and another Business, I tried to make a transaction of about 200$ and all went fine, the money were transferred, and I'm afraid because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What? No...think about what you just asked, if a merchant had access to buyers balance that is a huge privacy issue. Paypal will deal with balance issues, eg a back up source must be selected.

Comment: No, not by username and password, but something like an info by PayerID which I'm getting as parameter after payer login, I thought it is possible

Comment: Paypal is like a black box, things like balance/credit info are not given.